# Merging two different-dimension data frames based on column ID using panda

Tags: python

I have two panda data.frames

## df1

```
**Title** **ID**  
  Intro     A
   P1       B
   P2       C
  Concl     D
```

## df2

```
**body** **likes** **ID**
  Hello      1       A
  Stack      2       A
 Overflow    3       A
  How's      4       B
   It        5       C
  Going      6       C
    ?        7       D
```

I would like to merge the data frames based on ID, and have the resulting data frame:

## desired_df

```
**Title**  **ID**  **body**  **likes**
  Intro      A       Hello       1
  Intro      A       Stack       2
  Intro      A      Overflow     3
   P1        B       How's       4
   P2        C        It         5
   P2        C       Going       6
 Conclu      D        ?          7
```

The order of the columns don't matter (if df2 columns get ordered first before df1).

Is this possible? I want the values in the Title column for df1 to repeat as shown in desired data frame

Comment: Try something like `df1.concat(df2, ignore_indexes=True)`

Comment: See here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html

Answer (score 2):

How about this:

```
print(pandas.merge(df1, df2, on='ID', how='inner'))
```

I can not tell from your example if you want to perform an inner join or an outer join. However you can specify it by using the `how` parameter.

Doc: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.merge.html#pandas.merge